# Spock invocation test print too few information

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

Is it possible to make Spock give more information about failed tests.

Below test example only print the name booServices.someFunc when too few invocation. But in this case I would like see the exact name of booServices not the test name.
It is not a problem when too many invocation.

```
spyServices.each { Class<? extends FooServices> clazz, BooServices booServices ->
    (clazz in listOfExpected ? 1I : 0I) * booServices.someFunc(_)
}
```

This is what Spock print out, and here I would like to know the booServices real name:

> Too few invocations for:
>
> ```
> 1 * booServices.someFunc(_)   (0 invocations)
> ```

Comment: basically I want to rewrite TooFewInvocationsError

Comment: Where is your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Please give your question some more love, then you can expect quicker and better answers. Otherwise it is "garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: Can you give a specific example of the output you want to see?

Comment: I think it is pretty evident that the OP is no longer interested in an answer, because he did not react for one month. The problem seems to have a very low priority for him. So I voted to close the question, because it is lacking detail.